# Mongo use $set to add new field which copies a nested array object's value

Tags: mongodb

I want to use `$set` to copy a value which is nested in an array of objects to each object, but instead of copying that single value, it projects all the elements in an array. This is what I tried:

```
db.things.insertOne(
  {
    name: 'first',
    items: [
      { value: 1 },
      { value: 2 }
    ]
  }
)
```

```
db.things.updateMany(
  {},
  [
    {"$set": {"items.value_copy": "$items.value"}}
  ]
)
```

Outcome:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5e527707f3ae2e9f7adb6e1c"
  },
  "name": "first",
  "items": [
    {
      "value": 1,
      "value_copy": [
        1,
        2
      ]
    },
    {
      "value": 2,
      "value_copy": [
        1,
        2
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected outcome:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5e527707f3ae2e9f7adb6e1c"
  },
  "name": "first",
  "items": [
    {
      "value": 1,
      "value_copy": 1
    },
    {
      "value": 2,
      "value_copy": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

```
db.version();
```

> 4.2.3

Any idea how to get to my intended goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That issue is because `$items.value` would get a list of values at `items.values` from all documents. You can use aggregation pipeline in update operation, Which is introduced in MongoDB v`4.2` to re-write the entire `items` array with new field added to its each object :

```
db.thingsNew.update({}, [{
    $set: {
        items: {
            $map: {
                input: "$items",
                as : 'each',
                in: {
                    "value": "$$each.value",
                    "value_copy": "$$each.value"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}], { multi: true })
```

Comment: I used the same above query but it totally clean my array. only these two values got left ?

Comment: @MajidRehman: Not sure what you did, post your question & expected result along with what you've tried!

Comment: So you can see everything in the threat array is gone and I have only asset and assetId fields

Comment: @MajidRehman: Use this : https://mongoplayground.net !!
Generate a shareable link & paste it here, you can remove earlier comments.. I would say raise a new question & paste the link here!

Comment: please find this link, https://mongoplayground.net/p/Yz3nEo-jen2
 I have added one of my collection and also wrote the query. when you click on run, you can match the threat array, all of them is lost only asset and assetId left inside the threat array.
It should not remove other fields..

Comment: you can play around with my collection and can update query, thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Not possible

**Walkaround**. We use MongoDb Aggregation with `$map` to add `value_copy` field and `$out` operator override the collection.

```
db.things.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      items: {
        $map: {
          input: "$items",
          in: {
            "value": "$$this.value",
            "value_copy": "$$this.value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $out: "things"
  }
])
```